# Dynamically creating a picturebox from another class into a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having troubles with this part trying to create a picturebox into another form from another class, i hope I've provided enough information c:

Catelogue.cs <-- class that loads the picturebox

```
class Catelogue
{
    public void loadCatelogue()
    {
        mainPageGUI u = new mainPageGUI();

        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        u.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

        MessageBox.Show("HI");
    }
}
```

mainmenuGUI.cs < --- form that's calling loadcatelogue() to load picturebox

```
private void catelogueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Catelogue a = new Catelogue();
    a.loadCatelogue();
}
```

Comment: Currently, the picturebox isn't showing up in the mainmenuGUI form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the mainPageGUI form and add, to that instance, the new picturebox. This instance is not the one that calls your method and it is never showed. So your original instance remain unchanged and you don't see anything. (Just to demonstrate the problem try to change your MessageBox line with *u.Show();*)

To fix, just change your calling code and pass the form instance on which the picturebox should be created

```
private void catelogueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Catelogue a = new Catelogue();

    // pass this instance to the method....
    a.loadCatelogue(this);
}
```

and of course use the instance passed

```
public void loadCatelogue(mainPageGUI u)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
    pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
    pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    u.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
}
```