# c# - Dynamically creating picture box from dll into a form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to dynamically create a picture box by clicking a button. However, I want to have the code that creates the picture box (and also creates some graphs in that picture box) in a dll file.  When i move the code from my main form to a method in a dll file and then call that method in the button click event in my main form nothig happens.

I've been searching high and low for an answer but with little success. The most relevant thing that I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961375/dynamically-creating-a-picturebox-from-another-class-into-a-form). However, I struggle to create an instance of my main form to pass to the method in the dll...The answer might be bluntly obvious but I am very new to c#... Also, I am using Visual Studio 2013 if that is of any relevance.

Here is the method in the dll:

```
namespace DrillGraph
{
    public class DrillGraph : UserControl
    {
        public DrillGraph() { }

        public void CreateGraph()
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pb.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
            pb.Name = "pb";
            pb.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            pb.Location = new Point(20, 20);

            Graphics g = pb.CreateGraphics();

            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 50, 50);

            this.Controls.Add(pb);

        }            
    }
}
```

And this is what i have in my main form:

```
using DrillGraph;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                     

        }

        DrillGraph.DrillGraph dg = new DrillGraph.DrillGraph();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dg.CreateGraph();           

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Several bugs.  That DrawEllipse() call does nothing useful, use the Paint event instead.  And the form does not create the "dg" object correctly, it never got added to the form with Controls.Add().  You'd normally use the designer to do that.

Comment: Yes - it really doesn't do anything. I'll overwrite the OnPaint(), thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Adding where? you should provide the reference in your dll.

```
 public void CreateGraph(Panel pnl)
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pb.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        pb.Name = "pb";
        pb.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        pb.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        Graphics g = pb.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 50, 50);
        pnl.Controls.Add(pb);
    }
```

Then call below code

```
dg.CreateGraph(YourPanelName From Form);
```

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work - thanks for the advice.